# Partial usedrange selection in excel-VBA or how to select the consinuous part of a dynamic usedrange?

Tags: vba, excel

I have excel worksheets with a usedrange that consists of two dynamic tables/blocks.

On the right-hand side, there is table 1 with raw data (beginning in cell A1). Then, there is an empty column E:E (for example), followed by some formulas in a table beginning at F1 (for example).

I need to only clear the content of table 1. Table 2 needs to remain where it is and I was not yet able to figure out how.

When I do

```
   Set StartCell1 = Range("A1") ' select first cell of table 1
   StartCell1.CurrentRegion.Select ' attempt to select whole table 1
   Selection.ClearContents ' attempt to clear table 1
```

Both table 1 and table 2 are deleted.

**How to select only the subset of a usedrange that is continuous (i.e. no empty columns/rows) in excel-VBA?**

*Note that the dimensions of both tables as well as the number of blank columns in between varies between sheets.*

Comment: You need to avoid using the `.Select`. Instead you should look for LastRow, and LastColumn. There are plenty of posts on here that give you a way to calculate and implement those.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba?answertab=active#tab-top for lastrow

Comment: What happens when you manually select A1 and press Ctrl + Shift + *

Comment: needs to be a VBA Sub

Comment: I asked because there may be a mis-match between what you think Excel should be seeing as the `CurrentRegion` and what Excel is actually interpreting?  The shortcut is equivalent to VBA `Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select`

Comment: Seems something wrong with your worksheet. Otherwise codes seems okay...